# Bash looks like fork itself many times instead of once

Tags: linux, shell, docker, process

[image]

Hello,
I've run with bash `docker run ubuntu sleep 10000` and it is htop's output filtered with `sleep`.

```
2426 is a bash process
24*** is a docker-containe
25*** is a docker-containe
```

`PPID` means parent's pid. For my eye it looks like bash forked many times. But, AFAIK it cannot! If I put command to bash it should fork itself **once** and run a command in itself.

This is why I don't understand that output. Please exlpain me.

---

Edit after comments:

The bash's (2426) parent is `yakuake` (PID=2324), the parent of yakuake is kdeinit. I think that it doesn't matter.

Comment: That looks like `htop`... have you tried tree view? It can be quite informative. PID `25437` isn't listed... Please update the screenshot showing the parent bash process too.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from that output, can you post a `pstree` or `ps -ef`. You would normally have `dockerd > docker-container > docker-container > bash` in a process tree.